# MBP early 2013 so slow! please help!

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory

The institution I work in bought recently (early 2013) 8 MacBookPros 13' with 10.8 from an Apple store. (they are not Retina Display)

The problem is that my laptop is suuuuuper slow at doing regular stuff such as wake up. I have found that I type faster than my computer can handle and cannot keep up. This was happening from day 1. Now we are all realizing that it is happening to all our laptops. One of them simply stopped responding in usefull time (approx 15s to minimize a window). (I tave talked with my collegues and we all agree that these are the last Apple products we will buy)

The steps that reproduce the problem are as follows:
close the lid of the MBP, 
wait 15 seconds, 
open the lid, 
when the screen shows the request password window start typing your password. 
after normally 3 strokes (taking me 2 seconds to type) the laptop suddenly selects all my characters and whatever I continue to type it automatically substitutes my previous typing, obviously causing a bad password

I have at home another MBP with the same hardware, with a disk three times as full but twice as fast.

This particular laptop has been to a certified Apple repair shop for a change of logic board totally unrelated to the issue as the problem was here before and persists after the change in logic board, and since the problem is present in 7 other laptops bought at the same time. They ran a hardware diagnosis test and found no fault

Do you have any idea on what would cause 8 brand new laptops to come this bad? Why are 4 Gb of RAM not enough so that the computer keeps up with my typing?

Here is the screenshot of Activity Monitor:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a screenshots taken in Activity Monitor sorted by CPU usage and disk IO?

Comment: Let's close this temporarily for some editing since it's clear we need to play a little 20 questions to determine what is going on. Nuno - can you describe a sequence of steps that produces slow 15 second minimize a window from when you power up the Mac to cause the problem each and every time? (Or are the machines well behaved and only don't meet your expectations when they wake from sleep until the OS gets everything re-started after suspending the running apps?) If you know the machines have insufficient RAM - it seems you know what to do but if you are not sure, let's remove that part.

Comment: It was not my laptop that took 15 seconds to minimize a window, It was one of my collegues. Any sequence of steps show that this MBP is slower than a mid 2011 one I have at home! I know I have unsufficient RAM to run a lot of apps, but I will be outraged if I find that the default RAM Apple ships with the laptops is not enough for typesetting a password on the welcome screen. My questions are simple. What would cause these problems? Hardware? Software?

Comment: Hey patrix, you are a moderator, can you put my question back so that other people can answer it? Is there still something wrong with my question? Thank you

Comment: Can you please reread the comments above and provide the information people have asked for? This helps to prevent people from having to guess too much about the problem.

Comment: Is this a retina MBP? Have you tried taking it in to an Apple Store?

Comment: In case the steps to reproduce the problem are the only issue you are facing: I have the issue with my iMac here as well, that's "just" a nuisance but doesn't really indicate a performance issue.

Comment: maybe for you this is an acceptable nuisance but not for me, specially when 10.7 didn't have it but the new OS has. either way Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've found that when your MBP won't keep up with your typing it's generally because you're out of ram and in swap. It seems from the programs you're running, Python and IEP you are a developer.  My guess is you just have to much open for the amount of ram you have.  Perhaps Mavricks will help with that some but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: This cannot be the case as it started happening from day one of purchase when no programs were installed. And that does not explain either why would a 10.7 be able to keep up but not a 10.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will consider this question resolved as a moderator on this site said that he has the same problem on his iMac and that it is "just" a nuisance.

My opinion is that it is more than a nuisance! I will consider downgrading it to 10.7 as I know it is much faster on the same hardware

Thank you all for your replies

Comment: A temporary fix is to run `purge` in Terminal. This will take your inactive memory and "label" it as free memory. Also, in relation to the password error you mentioned in your question, see [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96639/how-might-text-be-selected-while-typing-the-login-password-on-my-mac/96647#96647).